# Google Script : multiple doPost in one project using MIT App inventor

Tags: android, google-apps-script

is there a way where I can configure multiple buttons on the MIT app inventor screen to do post different data to google sheet. as I understand, there can only be a single doPost() method in google script.

so if I have different button on app, and I wish to call different function in google app script I do not know what to use. what different identifier can I use in MIT app inventor for different buttons.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `parameters` for this by setting up your buttons in a way to direct to different urls, then retrieving the user's choice by making use of `e.parameters` in doGet(e).

**HTML code**

In your HTML template, you'd construct links / buttons to call your app using whatever parameter you want, eg.:

```
<!--The url comes from the template - see below-->

<a href="<?=url?>?functionOne=true">Function one</a>
<a href="<?=url?>?functionTwo=true">Function two</a>
```

**Script**

```
function doGet(e){
  var functionOne = e.parameter.functionOne;
  var functionTwo = e.parameter.functionTwo;
  
  //When functionOne is alled
  if (functionOne =="true"){

    //Do what you want here for function one
  }
  else if (functionTwo == "true"){

    //Do what you want here for function two
  }
  else {
  
  //This can be your base case here

  }
```

**URL in template**

You will want to include the script url before evaluating your template

```
template.url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
```